# Combine recurring payments (subscription) with Coinbase commerce

Tags: coinbase-api

I would like to combine [Coinbase commerce](https://commerce.coinbase.com), is that possible by setting up a [recurring payment button](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/merchants/recurring-payments), and linking to my Coinbase commerce address?

My requirement would be then to use Coinbase commece webhooks to be notified of payments.

Answer (score 1):

Since Coinbase Commerce only supports generating one-time payments through their API, it would be possible to do this using a separate web server, where you could interface with their API, creating charges and then receiving web-hook notifications when they are paid.
 
Having a separate service that controls the payment size and frequency of required payments would allow you to control payments at a finer detail than with a prebuilt service.

(High level question => High level answer)
Check out the api docs for ideas: https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/api/